# Tabs Root elements not visible

Tags: angular, ionic2, ionic3

I'm building ionic apps its has multi-account switch option. My problem is first time its Tabs root elements page visible good but when its switch to another account with specific tabs then its visible before render page. I will show my code for your better understand.

**app.components.ts**

```
import {Component, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import {Nav, Platform, PopoverController} from 'ionic-angular';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import {AuthProvider} from "../providers/auth";
import {SwitchAccountService} from "../providers/switch-account";

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class MyApp {

  rootPage: any;
  @ViewChild(Nav) nav: Nav;
  authentication:boolean=false;

  constructor(public platform: Platform,
              statusBar: StatusBar,
              splashScreen: SplashScreen,
              private auth:AuthProvider,
              public popoverCtrl: PopoverController,
              private switchAccountService: SwitchAccountService) {

    this.initializeApp(statusBar, splashScreen);

  }

  initializeApp(statusBar: StatusBar,
                splashScreen: SplashScreen) {

    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      statusBar.styleDefault();
      splashScreen.hide();

      this.auth.onSessionStore.subscribe(() => {

        if (this.auth.isAuthenticated == true) {
          this.authentication =true;
          this.initializeTabs();
        }else{
          this.authentication =false;
          this.nav.setRoot('login-page');
        }

      })

    })
  }

  initializeTabs(){

    setTimeout(() => {

      this.switchAccountService
        .getUserLabel()
        .subscribe(message =>{
          this.refreshTabs(message);
        });

    }, 1000);

  }

  refreshTabs(item){

    if( item == 'ADMIN'){
      this.nav.setRoot('page-admin-tabs');
    } else if(item == 'TEACHER'){
      this.nav.setRoot('page-teachers-tabs');
    } else{
      if(this.auth.currentUser.user_flag == 2){
        this.nav.setRoot('page-teachers-tabs');
      }else{
        this.nav.setRoot('page-students-tabs');
      }
    }



  }


  presentPopover(myEvent) {
    let popover = this.popoverCtrl.create('page-popover');
    popover.present({
      ev: myEvent
    });
  }

}
```

**app.html**

```
<ion-title class="custom-font"
           style="font-size: 2.1em;" text-center>
  DASHBOARD
</ion-title>

<ion-buttons end>
  <button ion-button icon-only (click)="presentPopover($event)">
    <ion-icon name="md-more"></ion-icon>
  </button>
</ion-buttons>
```

And two tabs one is `TeachersTabsPage` and another tabs is `AdminTabsPage`

**admin-tabs.ts**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {IonicPage, NavController, NavParams} from 'ionic-angular';
import {APP_ADMIN_TABS} from "../../constants";

@IonicPage({
  name: 'page-admin-tabs',
  priority: 'high'
})

@Component({
  selector: 'page-admin-tabs',
  templateUrl: 'admin-tabs.html',
})
export class AdminTabsPage {

  adminTabs =APP_ADMIN_TABS;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
  }


  ionViewDidEnter() {

  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad AdminTabsPage');
  }

}
```

**admin-tabs.html**

```
<ion-tabs tabsPlacement="top" tabsHighligh="true" selectedIndex="0">

  <ion-tab *ngFor="let tab of adminTabs"
           [tabIcon]="tab.icon"
           [tabTitle]="tab.label"
           [root]="tab.component">
  </ion-tab>

</ion-tabs>
```

**teachers-tabs.ts**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {IonicPage, NavController, NavParams} from 'ionic-angular';
import {APP_TEACHER_TABS} from "../../constants";

@IonicPage({
  name: 'page-teachers-tabs',
  priority: 'high'
})

@Component({
  selector: 'page-teachers-tabs',
  templateUrl: 'teachers-tabs.html',
})
export class TeachersTabsPage {

  teacherTabs =APP_TEACHER_TABS;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
              public navParams: NavParams) {
  }


  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad TeachersTabsPage');
  }

}
```

**teachers-tabs.html**

```
<ion-tabs tabsPlacement="top" tabsHighligh="true" selectedIndex="0">

  <ion-tab *ngFor="let tab of teacherTabs"
           [tabIcon]="tab.icon"
           [tabTitle]="tab.label"
           [root]="tab.component">
  </ion-tab>

</ion-tabs>
```

And **tabs.ts**

```
import {TabInterface} from "../models/tabsModels";

export const APP_STUDENT_TABS : TabInterface[] = [
  {
    label: 'RUNNING',
    cache: false,
    icon: 'md-bicycle',
    component: 'page-exam-running'
  },
  {
    label: 'PENDING',
    cache: false,
    icon: 'md-albums',
    component: 'page-pending-exam'
  },
  {
    label: 'COMPLETED',
    cache: false,
    icon: 'md-checkmark-circle-outline',
    component: 'page-completed-exam'
  }
];

export const APP_TEACHER_TABS : TabInterface[] = [
  {
    label: 'APPROVED',
    cache: false,
    icon: 'md-hand',
    component: 'page-approved-exam'
  },
  {
    label: 'COMPLETED',
    cache: false,
    icon: 'md-checkmark-circle-outline',
    component: 'page-published-exam'
  }
];

export const APP_ADMIN_TABS : TabInterface[] = [
  {
    label: 'TM',
    cache: false,
    icon: 'md-man',
    component:'page-teacher-management'
  },

  {
    label: 'SM',
    cache: false,
    icon: 'md-people',
    component:'page-student-management'
  },

  {
    label: 'CM',
    cache: false,
    icon: 'md-calculator',
    component:'page-courses-management'
  }
];
```

Here first time render **teachers-tabs.ts** and show selectedIndex element but when switch to **admin-tabs.ts** its show last rendering page.

Comment: What is the equivalent APP_ADMIN_TABS and APP_TEACHER_TABS?

Comment: those are array of objects of tabs.... @Gurbela

Comment: write this array

Comment: its are pre-define array of object.. like   {
    label: 'TM',
    cache: false,
    icon: 'md-man',
    component:'page-teacher-management'
  }

Comment: The problem is in the component name, Is it imported on tabs page?

Comment: i update code please check it ... @Gurbela

Comment: Do not use it *ngFor for <ion-tab></ion-tab>, 
write so <ion-tab [root]="homePage" tabIcon="md-hand"></ion-tab>
and in ts homePage: any = HomePage;

Comment: why we are not use *ngFor

Comment: You do not have to import it page in tabs-page

Comment: Please check carefully i inject it .. and i also get tabs in my rootpage but cache is problem..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got my solution. Just need to change following files

**app.componets.ts**

```
  initializeTabs(){

      this.switchAccountService
        .getUserLabel()
        .subscribe(message =>{
          this.refreshTabs(message);
        });
  }

  refreshTabs(item){

    if( item == 'ADMIN'){
      this.nav.setRoot('page-admin-tabs').then(() => this.selectTabIndex(0));
    } else if(item == 'TEACHER'){
      this.nav.setRoot('page-teachers-tabs').then(() => this.selectTabIndex(0));
    } else{
      if(this.auth.currentUser.user_flag == 2){
        this.nav.setRoot('page-teachers-tabs').then(() => this.selectTabIndex(0));
      }else{
        this.nav.setRoot('page-students-tabs').then(() => this.selectTabIndex(0));
      }
    }
  }

  private selectTabIndex(index: number) {
      let tabs = this.nav.getActiveChildNavs();
      if(tabs && tabs[0]) {
          tabs[0].select(index);
      }
  }
```

**Same as teachers-tabs.ts**

**admin-tabs.ts**

```
adminTabs = APP_ADMIN_TABS;
@ViewChild('myTabs') tabRef: Tabs;

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
}

ionViewDidEnter() {
    if (this.tabRef) {
        this.tabRef.select(0);
    }
}
```

**admin-tabs.html**

```
<ion-tabs #myTabs tabsPlacement="top" tabsHighligh="true">

  <ion-tab *ngFor="let tab of adminTabs"
           [tabIcon]="tab.icon"
           [tabTitle]="tab.label"
           [root]="tab.component">
  </ion-tab>

</ion-tabs>
```

**same as teachers-tab.html**